# Htaccess negation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

I use htaccess to parse seo-friendly requests.
Earlier my htaccess had these string to parse requests like **/some/request/**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /index.php?alias=$1 [QSA]
```

Now I have multilingual support on my site to parse requests like **/en/some/request/**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(en|de)(/)?([^.]*)$ /index.php?lng=$1&alias=$3 [QSA]
```

How to catch all old request without language part **/some/request/** and forward them to default language **/en/some/request/**

As I understand it should by something like it

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(en|de)
RewriteRule ^(.?)$ ru/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try your rules this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!en|de)/?(.+)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/?([^.]*)$ /index.php?lng=$1&alias=$2 [QSA,L]
```